# Autogenerated id in the custom slot in Amazon lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I am trying to create a custom slot for Alphanumeric entry in Amazon lex
(Since there is no pre-defined Built-In slot available for the Alphanumeric values)

But it always fails even after giving the synonyms, So could someone show me light for creating custom slot?

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 1):

Use AMAZON.Organization built in slot for capturing the Alphanumeric values or free text.